# How do you prove that if side limits exist at a point, then the limit of the function exists at that point

Tags: calculus, limits

How would you do an Epsilon-Delta proof for this theorem?

IF $\lim \limits_{x \to a^+}$  $f(x)$ = $\lim \limits_{x \to a^-}$ $f(x) = L$

THEN $\lim \limits_{x \to a}$  $f(x)$ = L

Comment: The tag ([tag:proof-theory]) is intended for questions about proof theory as a branch of mathematical logic, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-theory/info) and relevant [discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/the-proof-theory-tag-is-misused-too-often). It is not intended for all questions related to proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\varepsilon > 0$,

- there is $\delta_1 > 0$ such that for all $x \in (a-\delta_1, a)$, $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$, and
- there is $\delta_2 > 0$ such that for all $x \in (a, a + \delta_2)$, $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$.

Taking $\delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ gives a desired $\delta$.